# Replacing variables with grunt

Tags: javascript, json, gruntjs

I'm a bit new to grunt and am having trouble finding a solution for something.

I'm looking for a way to replace placeholder variables in a .js file with variables from another file (json), specifically by matching the placeholder value with a key in the json, as a grunt task.

E.g.

**.js file**

```
var title = {placeholder1};
```

**template file**

```
{placeholder1: "Bob's page"}
```

After running the task title should have the value of "Bob's page"

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you take a look at following grunt-tasks

1. https://github.com/outaTiME/grunt-replace
2. https://github.com/yoniholmes/grunt-text-replace

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Ok, great, I found grunt-text-replace but it wasn't exactly what I needed, grunt-replace looks like it is.